# Elasticsearch NEST 5.x Koelnerphonetic not matching

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

**UPDATE**
I changed the approach of the question

I'm trying to apply phonetic search with koelner phonetics and also ngram is used.

Index configuration I'm using:

```
    {
  "testnew": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "provided_name": "testnew",
        "creation_date": "1489672932033",
        "analysis": {
          "filter": {
            "koelnerPhonetik": {
              "replace": "false",
              "type": "phonetic",
              "encoder": "koelnerphonetik"
            }
          },
          "analyzer": {
            "koelnerPhonetik": {
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "koelnerPhonetik"
            },
            "ngram_analyzer": {
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "ngram_tokenizer"
            }
          },
          "tokenizer": {
            "koelnerPhonetik": {
              "type": "standard"
            },
            "ngram_tokenizer": {
              "token_chars": [
                "letter",
                "digit",
                "punctuation",
                "symbol"
              ],
              "min_gram": "2",
              "type": "ngram",
              "max_gram": "20"
            }
          }
        },
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ive got one document that looks like this:

```
{
    "_index": "testnew",
    "_type": "person",
    "_id": "3",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "name": "Can",
      "fields": {
        "phonetic": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "koelnerPhonetik"
        }
      }
    }
```

It is mapped like this:

```
GET testnew/person/_mapping
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "koelnerPhonetik"
          }
```

Why cant I find 'Can' by searching for 'Kan' in this query?

```
GET testnew/person/_search
      {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "name.phonetic": {
            "query": "Kan"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your field is called `name` not `name.keyword`

Comment: @Val This is not yielding any results, not sure why yet

Comment: Remove the `.keyword` as the analyzer is only working on your `name` field not `name.keyword` (which is not analyzed by definition)

Comment: @OHMR Your document source doesn't look correct for the mapping. The mapping doesn't contain the `multi_field` with the `koelnerPhonetik` analyzed `name.phonetic` sub field. Remove the `fields: { ... }` from the document and add it to the mapping under the `name` field.